# Ошибки при клонировании репозитория

Tags: git, gitlab

При клонировании репозитория возникают одни и те же ошибки.
Объем оперативной памяти - 12GB. Файл подкачки - 20 GB. Размер репозитория - 14 GB.
Как побороть эти ошибки?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пробовали ставить еще больше значение в `http.postBuffer`?

Comment: попробуйте не `git clone ..`, а `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git-daemon.exe clone ..`. Взято из https://coderoad.ru/34635599/Git-для-windows-со-смертельным-исходом-в-начале-EOF

Comment: не используйте coderoad - это обычная сайтопереводилка для SO. Давайте нормальные ссылки https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34635599/git-for-windows-fatal-early-eof

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: если подходить логически, то проблема тут скорее в сервере/канале связи, нежели в клиентской машине. я бы попробовал изменить транспортный протокол с http на ssh. @AlexGlebe, по приведённой вами ссылке речь тоже о проблеме сервера, но сервера, работающего под управлением ms/windows. к данному вопросу это не имеет никакого отношения.

Comment: Я не понял, вы клонируете репозиторий в другой (`iconcpa`), уже созданный ранее, репозиторий?! Попробуйте сделать `cd ..` перед тем, как клонировать.